# Simplifying overly convoluted result expressions from Resolve-Exists input

Tags: simplifying-expressions

This is a toy example for clarity; I would actually want to apply any method that works on more complicated inputs. (One variation of a more "real" problem is to bump up number of points and the polynomial order, but that makes it harder to come up with the good alternative solution to compare with.)

I want to check if three 2D points with distinct $x$ coordinates can be fit into a linear polynomial. A condition can be acquired using `Resolve` of `Exists`:

```
expr1 = Resolve[Exists[
    {a, b},
    a x + b == y /.
     {{x -> x1, y -> y1},
      {x -> x2, y -> y2},
      {x -> x3, y -> y3}}], Reals] //
  FullSimplify[# && x1 != x2 != x3, Element[_Symbol, Reals]] &

(* x2 != x3 && ((x1 == 0 && 
        x2 y1 + x3 y2 == 
         x3 y1 + x2 y3 && ((x1 != x2 && x3 != 0) || (x2 != 0 && 
            x1 != x3))) || (x2 y1 + x3 y2 + x1 y3 == 
         x3 y1 + x1 y2 + x2 y3 && x1 != 0 && x1 != x2 && x1 != x3)) *)
```

The problem is so simple that it's pretty obvious that the condition can be constructed differently, just checking that $x$ values are distinct and points collinear:

```
expr2 = CollinearPoints[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}] && 
  x1 != x2 != x3

(* x3 y1 + x1 y2 + x2 y3 == x2 y1 + x3 y2 + x1 y3 && x1 != x2 != x3 *)
```

These expressions are equivalent:

```
Resolve[ForAll[
  {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3}, 
  Equivalent[expr1, expr2]], Reals]

(* True *)
```

The problem here is that `expr1` is clearly more complicated than necessary and it's not obvious to me how to tweak `Resolve`, `FullSimplify` or whatever to produce more compact result. With the toy problem this is not much of an issue but results become quickly less understandable as complexity of inputs increases.

Comment: I suspect that any possible solution will be strictly tailored to the problem, so solutions that apply to this toy problem almost certainly will not solve your actual issue. You should probably share that actual issue instead.

Comment: @MarcoB "Real" problems are a bit diverse. I have seen various outputs blow up *a lot* though. One variation is to increase the polynomial order for this fitting test expression. The toy problem is convenient in the sense that you can construct an alternative solution just by thinking of geometry...